# Is there a means with which to constrain a random variable in a class based upon the result of the randomization of another var?

Tags: oop, system-verilog

I need to randomize variable `rA` and set variable `rB` to 1'b1 if `rA` == 1'b1 or randomized if `rA` == 1'b0. Here is what I am trying:

```
class randomizedVars;
    rand bit rA;
    rand bit rB;
    constraint cB {
        rB == 1'b1;
    }
    task changeConstraints();
        if (this.rA == 1'b1)
            begin
            this.cB.constraint_mode(1); // turn on the constraint for rB
            this.rA.rand_mode(0); // Disable rA from being randomized
            this.randomize(); // Rerandomize to force rB to meet its constraint ?
            this.rA.rand_mode(1); // Reenable rA to be randomized later
            this.cB.constraint_mode(0); // turn off the constraint for rB for later
            end
         else
            this.cB.constraint_mode(0);
    endtask
endclass
```

This method seems to be working, but I'm mostly just wondering if there is a "correct" way of doing this. I feel as if this method is the Brute-Force-And-Difficulty method. Worse yet, I need to call the task after every randomization, which makes me feel as if there is a method I am not seeing.

Just to be clear, my expected results are that when `rA` is randomized and equal to 1, `rB` will be forced to 1. If `rA` is randomized and equal to 0, then `rB` will also be randomized. My actual results match this. Just wondering if there is a way to do this without having to call a task after every `.randomize()` method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code by using a different constraint and removing the task.

```
class randomizedVars;
    rand bit rA;
    rand bit rB;

    constraint cB {
        solve rA before rB;
        (rA == 1) -> (rB == 1);
    }
endclass

module tb;

randomizedVars c;

initial begin
    c = new();
    repeat (8) begin
        c.randomize();
        $display("a=%b b=%b", c.rA, c.rB);
    end    
end

endmodule
```

Here is an example print out:

```
a=0 b=0
a=0 b=1
a=1 b=1
a=1 b=1
a=0 b=0
a=1 b=1
a=0 b=0
a=0 b=1
```

If `rA` is randomly selected to be 1, then `rB` will be forced to 1; otherwise, `rB` will be random.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called an *implication* constraint (Section 18.5.6 in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595).

> *expression* -> *constraint_set*

If can also be written as

> if (*expression*) *constraint_set*

But the first is preferred since the is an equation, not procedural code. In either case, when the LHS expression is true, the constraints on the RHS must be satified.

```
constraint cB {
     (rA == 1) -> (rB == 1);
}
```